# Text defaults to vertical with too many objects on slide ReporteRs R

Tags: r, reporters

When I put more than nine objects on a slide, the newest objects default to vertical (this happens with text, not sure about plots or images).  My company does have a habit of putting too much information on the slide, but they want to keep the same format, if at all possible.  I wasn't sure if the ReporteRs package had an option to set the maximum number of objects or maybe this is an issue with one of the dependencies to run the package.  I will attach a screenshot and the code.  I created a blank document titled Presentation1.pptx and put that in my working directory.

[image]

Code:

```
library("ReporteRs")

pres <- pptx(template = "Presentation1.pptx")
pres <- addSlide(pres, slide.layout = 'Blank')

pres <- addParagraph(par.properties = parProperties(),
                 doc = pres, text.align = "left", value = pot("SOME TEXT", 
                 textBold(color = "black", font.size = 36, font.family = "Arial")),
                 offx = 0.5, offy = 0, width = 0, height = 1)

pres <-addParagraph(par.properties = parProperties(list.style = "unordered", level = 1),
                doc = pres, text.align = "left", value = pot("Some Text",
                textBoldItalic(color = "black", font.size = 21, font.family = "Arial")),
                offx = 0.25, offy = 1, width = 0, height = 1)

pres <-addParagraph(par.properties = parProperties(list.style = "unordered", level = 2),
                doc = pres, text.align = "left", value = pot("Some Text",
                textBoldItalic(color = "black", font.size = 17, font.family = "Arial")),
                offx = 0.75, offy = 1.5, width = 0, height = 1)

pres <-addParagraph(par.properties = parProperties(list.style = "unordered", level = 2),
                doc = pres, text.align = "left", value = pot("Some Text",
                textBoldItalic(color = "black", font.size = 17, font.family = "Arial")),
                offx = 0.75, offy = 2, width = 0, height = 1)

pres <-addParagraph(par.properties = parProperties(list.style = "unordered", level = 1),
                doc = pres, text.align = "left", value = pot("Some Text",
                textBoldItalic(color = "black", font.size = 21, font.family = "Arial")),
                offx = 0.25, offy = 2.5, width = 0, height = 1)

pres <-addParagraph(par.properties = parProperties(list.style = "unordered", level = 2),
                doc = pres, text.align = "left", value = pot("Some Text",
                textBoldItalic(color = "black", font.size = 17, font.family = "Arial")),
                offx = 0.75, offy = 3, width = 0, height = 1)

pres <-addParagraph(par.properties = parProperties(list.style = "unordered", level = 2),
                doc = pres, text.align = "left", value = pot("Some Text",
                textBoldItalic(color = "black", font.size = 17, font.family = "Arial")),
                offx = 0.75, offy = 3.5, width = 0, height = 1)

pres <-addParagraph(par.properties = parProperties(list.style = "unordered", level = 2),
                doc = pres, text.align = "left", value = pot("Some Text",
                textBoldItalic(color = "black", font.size = 17, font.family = "Arial")),
                offx = 0.75, offy = 4, width = 0, height = 1)

pres <-addParagraph(par.properties = parProperties(list.style = "unordered", level = 2),
                doc = pres, text.align = "left", value = pot("Some Text",
                textBoldItalic(color = "black", font.size = 17, font.family = "Arial")),
                offx = 0.75, offy = 4.5, width = 0, height = 1)

pres <-addParagraph(par.properties = parProperties(list.style = "unordered", level = 2),
                doc = pres, text.align = "left", value = pot("Some Text",
                textBoldItalic(color = "black", font.size = 17, font.family = "Arial")),
                offx = 0.75, offy = 5, width = 0, height = 1)

pres <-addParagraph(par.properties = parProperties(list.style = "unordered", level = 2),
                doc = pres, text.align = "left", value = pot("Copyright Text",
                textBoldItalic(color = "black", font.size = 17, font.family = "Arial")),
                offx = 3, offy = 7, width = 0, height = 1)

writeDoc(pres, file = "pres.pptx")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, move to package `officer` if possible and read that page: https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/articles/powerpoint.html#append-text-sequentially-in-a-shape.

In you script, you are using widths set to 0 and a new shape for each new paragraph. `text.align` is not an argument of addParagraph. So let' simplify:

```
library(ReporteRs)
pres <- pptx()
pres <- addSlide(pres, slide.layout = 'Title and Content')

style_36 <- textBold(color = "black", font.size = 36, font.family = "Arial")
style_17 <- textBoldItalic(color = "black", font.size = 17, font.family = "Arial")
style_21 <- textBoldItalic(color = "black", font.size = 21, font.family = "Arial")

par_lev_1 <- parProperties(list.style = "unordered", level = 1)
par_lev_2 <- parProperties(list.style = "unordered", level = 2)
par_lev_3 <- parProperties(list.style = "unordered", level = 3)

pres <- addParagraph(par.properties = parProperties(), doc = pres, value = pot("SOME TEXT", style_36),
                     offx = 0.5, offy = 0, width = 8, height = 6)

pres <-addParagraph(par.properties = par_lev_1, append = TRUE, 
                    doc = pres, value = pot("Some Text", style_21) )

pres <-addParagraph(par.properties = par_lev_2, append = TRUE, 
                    doc = pres, value = pot("Some Text", style_17) )

pres <-addParagraph(par.properties = par_lev_2, append = TRUE, 
                    doc = pres, value = pot("Some Text", style_17) )

pres <-addParagraph(par.properties = par_lev_3, append = TRUE, 
                    doc = pres, value = pot("Some Text", style_21) )

pres <-addParagraph(par.properties = par_lev_2, append = TRUE, 
                    doc = pres, value = pot("Some Text", style_17) )

pres <-addParagraph(par.properties = par_lev_2, append = TRUE, 
                    doc = pres, value = pot("Some Text", style_17) )

pres <-addParagraph(par.properties = par_lev_2, append = TRUE, 
                    doc = pres, value = pot("Some Text", style_17) )

pres <-addParagraph(par.properties = par_lev_2, append = TRUE, 
                    doc = pres, value = pot("Some Text",style_17) )

pres <-addParagraph(par.properties = par_lev_2, append = TRUE, 
                    doc = pres, value = pot("Some Text", style_17) )

pres <-addParagraph(par.properties = par_lev_3, append = TRUE, 
                    doc = pres, value = pot("Copyright Text", style_21) )

writeDoc(pres, file = "pres.pptx")
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and help!  I will look into the officer package.

Comment: One follow up question, using this method, is there a way to set the location of the text?  When I try commands offx and offy I get an error that I need width and height, when I set the text to the proper location.

Comment: I am not sure to understand. In the first call, a new paragraph is added and that's where the position is defined (yes, you need also width and height), then it only append in the new existing text shape. All the text belong to the same shape.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you for the explanation.